# Windows 10 nokia lumia 720 too slow

Tags: insider-preview, nokia-lumia-720

I have been using Windows 10 preview for almost 2-3 months now. I have serious issues with the phone being too slow and laggy. I am not sure what I should do to fix it.

A post on the Microsoft forums says to reset the device. But if I reset the device will it not go back to Windows 8.1?

I'll surely reset the device once I am up to date on build 10536. However is there any other way that I might be able to speed up the device? Right now it's completely clean so don't suggest to clean apps and cache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding the slowing down of the phone - this is something that a lot of users in the preview have complained about. Microsoft has stated repeatedly that the Preview is not intended for productive use. Looking at the Windows 10 Preview for Desktop I had similar issues that got fixed until the launch.

There are rumors that Microsoft removed the Android Runtime ([Project Astoria](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/bridges/android)) in the latest preview build because of performance concerns, maybe this version will run better for a longer time.

Comment: Which one is the latest built? Also, why was Microsoft using android runtime for Windows 10 device. Can you please elaborate your ANSWER? I didn't knew that.

Comment: Microsoft is building a tool to make it easier to port Android apps to Windows Mobile, called Project Astoria (included the link in my answer). Thats what the runtime is for. Latest build is 10.0.1549.4 afaik

Comment: to get latest built i.e. 10.0.1549.4 should I choose fast update from Insider app? @Thomas

Comment: yes, but you have to roll back to 8.1 first - that's currently the only way

Comment: So that means I have to roll back via Windows Recovery tool to 8.1 and then I will get it?

Comment: Yes, when you re-join the insider program

Comment: Microsoft acknowledged that 10536 had an issue that slowed performance after some time. So far this seems to be fixed for me in 10559.

Comment: @Thomas I reverted back to Windows 8.1 however I don't get any updates now. Even after joining insider program and enabling fast updates from the insider app.

Comment: The error I get is we are current unable to check for updates(801881e4). This error is for internet not connected. However my wifi works fine. Any Idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Doing a hardware reset will take it back to factory conditions, for the currently installed OS. To get the latest insider preview, you'd need to use the Lumia Recovery tool to go back to 8.1, and then roll forward to 10 as there was a bug discovered going from the previous Windows 10 build.

Doing a factory reset will remove all user content (installed apps, photos, etc) and lead through the first run experience when you turn it back on - be sure to back up what you want to keep before resetting.